# Duplicate suggestion in monaco editor react next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I am using monaco-edtor to create a formula editor in React and Nextjs, I have an edit button to show and hide the editor, the editor only gets shown/mounted only when the user clicks the edit button.

at first, mounting the suggestion is coming as intended, but when the user hides and shows the editor same elements are repeated again as shown in the picture below is there any way to correct this

The photo of the suggestion window.

1. First-time mounting
   [image]
2. Second-time mounting
   [image]
3. Third-time mounting
   [image]

My blue print of my code is like

```js
export const MonacoEditor = () => {
const editorRef = useRef<monacoEditor.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor | null>(
        null,
    );
    
function HandleEditorDidMount(
        editor: monacoEditor.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor,
        monaco: typeof monacoEditor,
    ) {
        editorRef.current = editor;

        editorRef.current.onKeyDown((event: monacoEditor.IKeyboardEvent) => {
            if (event.keyCode === monaco.KeyCode.Enter) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        // Define your custom language
        monaco.languages.register({
            id: "custom-language",
        });

        editorRef.current.updateOptions({
            lineNumbers: "off",
            lineDecorationsWidth: 1,
            tabCompletion: "off",
            selectionHighlight: false,
            renderLineHighlight: "none",
            minimap: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            overviewRulerLanes: 0,
            scrollbar: {
                horizontal: "hidden",
                handleMouseWheel: true,
            },
            wordWrapColumn: -1,
            wordWrap: "on",
        });
        monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider("custom-language", {
            provideCompletionItems: async (_model, position) => {
                const currentWord = getCurrentWord(editorRef.current, position);

                // Make a request to your backend API to fetch suggestions based on the user's input
                const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/fewLabels", {
                    method: "GET",
                });

                const suggestions: Suggestion = await response.json();
                console.log("suggestions ", suggestions);
                const completionItems = Object.keys(suggestions)
                    .filter((keyword) =>
                        keyword.toLowerCase().startsWith(currentWord.toLowerCase()),
                    )
                    .map((keyword) => ({
                        label: keyword,
                        id: keyword,
                        kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
                        insertText: keyword,
                        range: new monaco.Range(
                            position.lineNumber,
                            position.column - currentWord.length,
                            position.lineNumber,
                            position.column,
                        ),
                    }));

                console.log("completionItems ", completionItems);

                return {
                    suggestions: completionItems,
                };
            },
        });
    }

return(
         <Editor
                height="70px"
                width={"800px"}
                defaultLanguage="custom-language"
                onMount={HandleEditorDidMount}
            />
       )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem I added a state `completionDisposable` and seated the function returned by the `monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider` to it and called as a clean-up function useEffect the modified code is given below

The modification is followed by the comments `// Beginning of Added Segment`

and `// Setting the disposable object`

*if you understood and works for you don't forget to upvote*

```js
export const MonacoEditor = () => {
    const editorRef = useRef<monacoEditor.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor | null>(
        null,
    );

    // Beginning of Added Segment
    const [completionDisposable, setCompletionDisposable] = useState<monacoEditor.IDisposable>();

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if (
                completionDisposable?.dispose &&
                typeof completionDisposable.dispose === "function"
            ) {
                completionDisposable.dispose();
            }
        };
    }, [completionDisposable]);

    // End of added segment



    function HandleEditorDidMount(
        editor: monacoEditor.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor,
        monaco: typeof monacoEditor,
    ) {
        editorRef.current = editor;

        editorRef.current.onKeyDown((event: monacoEditor.IKeyboardEvent) => {
            if (event.keyCode === monaco.KeyCode.Enter) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });


        // Define your custom language
        monaco.languages.register({
            id: "custom-language",
        });

        editorRef.current.updateOptions({
            lineNumbers: "off",
            lineDecorationsWidth: 1,
            tabCompletion: "off",
            selectionHighlight: false,
            renderLineHighlight: "none",
            minimap: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            overviewRulerLanes: 0,
            scrollbar: {
                horizontal: "hidden",
                handleMouseWheel: true,
            },
            wordWrapColumn: -1,
            wordWrap: "on",
        });

        // Setting the disposable object
        setCompletionDisposable(
            monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider("custom-language", {
                provideCompletionItems: async (_model, position) => {
                    const currentWord = getCurrentWord(editorRef.current, position);

                    // Make a request to your backend API to fetch suggestions based on the user's input
                    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/fewLabels", {
                        method: "GET",
                    });

                    const suggestions: Suggestion = await response.json();
                    console.log("suggestions ", suggestions);
                    const completionItems = Object.keys(suggestions)
                        .filter((keyword) =>
                            keyword.toLowerCase().startsWith(currentWord.toLowerCase()),
                        )
                        .map((keyword) => ({
                            label: keyword,
                            id: keyword,
                            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
                            insertText: keyword,
                            range: new monaco.Range(
                                position.lineNumber,
                                position.column - currentWord.length,
                                position.lineNumber,
                                position.column,
                            ),
                        }));

                    console.log("completionItems ", completionItems);

                    return {
                        suggestions: completionItems,
                    };
                },
            }),
        );
    }


    return (
        <Editor
            height="70px"
            width={"800px"}
            defaultLanguage="custom-language"
            onMount={HandleEditorDidMount}
        />
    );
};
```